# InfluxDB critical alert when values ​are not equal

Tags: influxdb, flux

I have alerting when I need a value greater than 5. It works and everything is fine with that.

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/monitor"
import "influxdata/influxdb/v1"

data = from(bucket: "my_bucket")
    |> range(start: -15s)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_mes")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["service"] == "test_service")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["action"] == "differ")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["env"] == "production")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["response_code"] == "400")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 15s, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)

option task = {name: "differ_task", every: 15s, offset: 0s}

check = {_check_id: "12345", _check_name: "check_differ", _type: "threshold", tags: {differ_tag: "1"}}
crit = (r) => r["value"] > 5.0
messageFn = (r) => "Check: ${ r._check_name } is: ${ r._level }"

data |> v1["fieldsAsCols"]() |> monitor["check"](data: check, messageFn: messageFn, crit: crit)
```

However, I need to change the alerting so that it occurs when there is a difference (no matter which way) between the values.

Let's say the result of the sum of

```
r["response_code"] == "0"
```

and

```
r["response_code"] == "200"
```

in 15 seconds - not equal.

I tried to write a custom query, using the visual tools I did not find how to do it. However, this query does not work as I need. Is it possible to do this at all? Perhaps with the help of variables and their subsequent comparison?

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/monitor"
import "influxdata/influxdb/v1"

data = from(bucket: "my_bucket")
    |> range(start: -15s)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_mes")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["service"] == "test_service")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["action"] == "differ")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["env"] == "production")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["response_code"] == "0")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 15s, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)

data2 = from(bucket: "my_bucket")
    |> range(start: -15s)
    |> filter(fn: (r2) => r2["_measurement"] == "my_mes")
    |> filter(fn: (r2) => r2["service"] == "test_service")
    |> filter(fn: (r2) => r2["action"] == "differ")
    |> filter(fn: (r2) => r2["env"] == "production")
    |> filter(fn: (r2) => r2["response_code"] == "200")
    |> filter(fn: (r2) => r2["_field"] == "value")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 15s, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)

option task = {name: "differ_task", every: 15s, offset: 0s}

check = {_check_id: "12345", _check_name: "check_differ", _type: "threshold", tags: {differ_tag: "1"}}
crit = (r) => r["value"] != r2["value"]
messageFn = (r) => "Check: ${r._check_name} is: ${r._level}"

data |> v1["fieldsAsCols"]() |> monitor["check"](data: check, messageFn: messageFn, crit: crit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import "experimental"
import "math"

start = from(bucket: "my_bucket")
    |> range(start: -15s)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_mes")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["action"] == "differ")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["response_code"] == "0")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["env"] == "production")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["service"] == "test_service")
    |> experimental.count()
    |> yield(name: "start")

success = from(bucket: "my_bucket")
    |> range(start: -15s)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_mes")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["action"] == "recalculate")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["response_code"] == "200")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["env"] == "production")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["service"] == "test_service")
    |> experimental.count()
    |> yield(name: "success")

resStart = start
    |> findColumn(
        fn: (key) => key._field == "value",
        column: "_value",
    )
resSuccess = success
    |> findColumn(
        fn: (key) => key._field == "value",
        column: "_value",
    )
//difference >= 4.0 do some alert
if math.abs(x: float(v: resStart[0]) - float(v: resSuccess[0])) >= 4.0 then
    #DO SOME ALERT
else
    0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.